# How to calculate effective tax rate in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math

I currently have an array of intervals that can be used to tell me what that tax rate is for that salary.

```
let tree = new IntervalTree();

// 2020 Federal Income Tax Brackets for Single
let singleIntervals = [
  [0, 9875],
  [9876, 40125],
  [40126, 85525],
  [85526, 163300],
  [163301, 207350],
  [207351, 518400],
  [518401, 900000000],
];

tree.insert(singleIntervals[0], 10);
tree.insert(singleIntervals[1], 12);
tree.insert(singleIntervals[2], 22);
tree.insert(singleIntervals[3], 24);
tree.insert(singleIntervals[4], 32);
tree.insert(singleIntervals[5], 35);
tree.insert(singleIntervals[6], 37);
```

So I can use this `let values_in_range = tree.search([10000, 10000]);` to get the tax rate for someone with a salary of $10,000 which is `12%`. But I found out that the way federal income tax works is that you are taxed in chunks.

[image: Example].

So if I have a $50,000 salary, then "you’d pay 10% on that first $9,875 and 12% on the chunk of income between $9,876 and $40,125. And then you’d pay 22% on the rest, because some of your $50,000 of taxable income falls into the 22% tax bracket. The total bill would be about $6,800 — about 14% of your taxable income, even though you’re in the 22% bracket. That 14% is called your effective tax rate."

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like the following

```js
const income = 50000;

let totalTaxes = 0;

if (income < 9875) {
  totalTaxes += income * 0.1;
}
else {
  totalTaxes += 9875 * 0.1;
  if (income < 40125) {
    totalTaxes += (income - 9875) * 0.12;
  }
  else {
    totalTaxes += (40125 - 9875) * 0.12;
    //et cetera
  }
}
```

**edit: dynamic solution** 
I changed the intervals array to make it simpler: first element is the upper limit of the previous and the third element is the tax rate. 
Outputs 6790

```js
const singleIntervals = [
  [0, 9875, 0.1],
  [9875, 40125, 0.12],
  [40125, 85525, 0.22],
  [85525, 163300, 0.24],
  [163300, 207350, 0.32],
  [207350, 518400, 0.35],
  [518400, 900000000, 0.37],
];

const income = 50000;

let totalTaxes = 0;
for (const interval of singleIntervals) {
  if (income < interval[1]) {
    totalTaxes += (income - interval[0]) * interval[2];
    break;
  }
  else {
    totalTaxes += (interval[1] - interval[0]) * interval[2];
  }
}

console.log(totalTaxes);
```

Comment: Your solution isn't dynamic; ie. since it doesn't use the array of intervals from the question, you'd need to code in each of the intervals directly if you have an income that's higher than the third bracket, which is a lot less than ideal.

Comment: I added a dynamic solution also

Comment: the dynamic solution works perfect. Only thing is, it works on PlayCode.io but when I run it in my function in my project it return NaN. Any idea why?

Comment: I edited the `singleIntervals` array, did you change the one in your project?